# Designing a simple Login section in the Navbar of a HTML Page?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I am creating a welcome page with a login section at the navbar. I managed to create the entire page's div sections however I need help with css coding the navbar.

**CSS of what I have right now:**

```
div.col-4
{
    width:41%;
    float:left;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 100%;
}

div.col-6
{
    width:58%;
    float:right;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 100%;
}

#topbar-hello{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#0084fd;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>

    <div id="topbar-hello">  
          <!-- This is where I need to add the login section --> 
     </div>

    <div class="col-4">

    </div>

    <div class="col-6">

    </div>
</body>
```

**This is what I have right now:**

[image]

**I need to add a login area (2 textboxes and spans as given below) to the navbar:**

[image]

I am having difficulty understanding how to fit those two textboxes, 3 labels and checkbox to the navbar.

Can you point out the CSS code for the navbar to achieve the above login area?

Comment: [Bootstrap Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) might help you a lot.

Comment: I am trying to write without using Bootstrap for learning purposes :) @rmondesilva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a code inside navbar's div. You can use `table` in that style of log-in form.

```
<div id="topbar-hello">  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Email
      </td>
      <td>
        Password
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>
         Log In
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Remember me 
      </td>
      <td>
        Forgot Password
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
      <!-- This is where I need to add the login section --> 
</div>

<div class="col-4">

</div>

<div class="col-6">

</div>
```

You can see it live here, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pwvd541/).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to increase the height of the nav bar. Then use HTML to add the login area.

It would look a bit like this:

```
<body>

    <p>Email</p>
    <p>Password</p>

    <p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
        <button>Log in</button>
    </p>

</body>
```

You can then style it as you would like.

Comment: Yes I wanted to know the styling to achieve that look in the 2nd pic. That was the question :)

Comment: @Earthling I would change the margin-left/margin-top values of each of the input/p tags.